# How to assign a type to an object in TypeScript based on switch case

Tags: typescript, switch-statement, typescript-typings, typescript-types

I'm building a React Native app with TypeScript.

I'm writing a handler with a switch case like this:

```
export const handleMessageData = (dispatch: Dispatch, messageData: FCMMessage): void => {
  const { type, message_data } = messageData;
  const data = camelizeKeys(JSON.parse(message_data));
    switch (type) {
        case conditionOne:
          data.consumer = data.consumer.uuid;
          setHouses({ entities: { houses: { [data.uuid]: data } } });
        // ... more cases
        default:
          // ... do stuff
      }
    };
```

In each case I know of which type `data` is. How can I tell typescript that?

Pseudo code:

```
case conditionOne:
  data: MyType;
  data.consumer = data.consumer.uuid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More code around your `switch` would be helpful (eg. where do `type` and `data` come from, and what do they look like?). In general, you can use a tagged union, object type, record type, or a number of other ways to declare a relationship between two types.

Comment: I added the extra code around the switch statement. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great! This should work if you type `FCMMessage` correctly. The feature you want to use here is discriminated unions (sometimes people also call it "tagged unions"). The key is to type `FCMMessage` as a union of possible messages, where every member of that union has a `type` property with a string literal type. See an example here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions